# Is it possible to remove meta viewport with a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport

I don't have access to the HTML file to get to it from the server side, however I can add additional HTML to the site. MY question is I have a non responsive site listed below, that now because of the new viewport code, I have to ZOOM IN once the site loads, to see the entire site.

WEBSITE
http://www56.myfantasyleague.com/2017/home/51277

I was trying this, but to no avail.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('head').remove('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />');
   $("head").append('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />');
</script>
```

A perfect situation would be to block or remove the viewport, and have the site load as a non responsive website as it was before.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Or you can just try this (Don't need jQuery):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['viewport'].content='initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no';
```

Comment: I added your code also the same method <script>YOUR CODE</script> and same result.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `.remove()` must be a selector, not an HTML string.

```
$("head meta[name=viewport]:contains(initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width)").remove();
```

Comment: I added your code to a inside spot that works like HTML and selected header by default. once you click the link to my site on mobile, it to me still loads just the same (zoomed out)... Can you see if I have the code correctly coded to add please?              <script>  $("head meta[name=viewport]:contains(initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width)").remove();</script>

Comment: Again I don't have access to the main HTML file from the server, just have the ability to add HTML from within the site that I assume is embedded. Maybe since this is loading after the main HTML, I assume that might be a problem?

Comment: When you examine the DOM after it loads, is the meta tag removed?

Comment: I wish I knew how to see but I don't...I don't have access to the main HTML so I am trying to beat the page load to remove the meta viewport on mobiles ........if you think this can work, can you tell me the exact code you want me to add to the site to check and see please.

Comment: I'm talking about examining the DOM in the browser's Developer Tools console. You don't need access to the main HTML.

Comment: I added your code back to the inner HTML with header checked......can you check the DOM as I don't quiet know how to do that and what I need to look for realistically...please